# Separate values out of semicolon delimited string with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, delimiter

I need help for a regular expression. 
My search can't find something useful so far. My string looks like:

```
E32;E223;E0;A1023
```

I would like to get the values `E32` and `E223` and `E0` and `A1023`.

What is the best regex syntax for it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Usually you don't need regular expression for this: Your language would support split: `"E32;E223;E0;A1023".split(";")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this: `[^;]+` or `\w+`.
This will give you every semicolon separated token, and will exclude empty tokens.

Edit: also you can and should use `"E32;E223;E0;A1023".split(";")` like falsetru mentioned in the comments (providing your language supports this -> which it probably does).